# Issue with manipulating fragment with Google map:

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have this `Fragment`:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {

private static final LatLng SOME_PLACE = new LatLng(32.073229,34.773231);
private GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<CoffeeShop> coffeeShopsList;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, null, false);   
    map =  ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    coffeeShopsList = (ArrayList<CoffeeShop>) ((CupsDemoApplication)getActivity().getApplication()).getCoffeeShopsList();

    for (CoffeeShop tempCoffeeShop: coffeeShopsList)
    {
         Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(tempCoffeeShop.getCoffeeShopLat()), Double.parseDouble(tempCoffeeShop.getCoffeeShopLng())))
        .title(tempCoffeeShop.getCoffeeShopName())
        .snippet(tempCoffeeShop.getCoffeeShopAddress())
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinplace_turkiz)));
    }       

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SOME_PLACE, 2));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);

    return v;
}

public void zoomToSelectedCoffeeShop(LatLng latlng)
{
    Log.d("EMIL", "latlng: "+latlng );
    if (map == null)
    {
        map =  ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 
    }
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 2));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17), 2000, null);  
}
 }
```

It's placed in a `ViewPager` and works well until i call the `zoomToSelectedCoffeeShop`
method. I get a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
map =  ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and I can't figure out why. This method is call from outside of the `Fragmnet` (another `Fragment` or the Activity). How would I get the instance of the `SupportMapFragment` to manipulate it?

Here is the `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ShopsListFragment.ARG_QUESTION_NUMBER, position);
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ShopsListFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MyMapFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.coffee_shops_section).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.map_section).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: How do you do your fragment transactions?  Do you use `add()` and `hide()` or do you use `replace()`?

Comment: i'm using a FragmentPagerAdapter so it basiclly does all the work for me. I don't use fragment transactions.

Comment: Not sure if this is the kind of answer you want, but maybe you could move to that fragment in your FragmentPagerAdapter and then zoom to the coffee shop.

Comment: @AndrewSchuster what do you mean by that? to run this method from the main container activity this is what i did: ((MyMapFragment)mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1)).zoomToSelectedCoffeeShop(latlng);

Comment: Okay, I looked it up in the documentation and I don't know if you can do it the way I just said.  Could you maybe post your FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: Shouldn't your `MyMapFragment` extend `SupportMapFragment` instead of just `Fragment`?

Comment: I tried it but that didn't worked for me.

Comment: You should not be adding nested fragments via xml. Read [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) on it. Your own answer is touching basic programming principles of encapsulation and loose coupling.

Comment: @MaciejGórski so how should I do that? Yes I know that what I did isn't really good. I just didn't find another way to manipulate the map using the method inside the fragment. I would always get a NullPointerException on the map object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue and to manipulate the map from the activity I passed the instance of the
map to the activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (map == null) {
        map = fragment.getMap();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);   
    this.activity = (MainActivity) activity;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    activity.setMap(map);
}
```

When `setMap(map)` of the `Activity` is:

```
public void setMap(GoogleMap map)
{
    this.map = map;
}
```

then in the Activity I can manipulate the map:

```
@Override
public void onCoffeeShopSelected(LatLng latlng) 
{
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 14));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17), 2000, null);  
}
```